# How to solve shift/reduce conflicts in parser grammar

Tags: perl, parsing, grammar, yacc

I'm learning how to write parsers, and to do so, I'm writing parser for SQL.

Grammar I'm writing is processed by perl [Parse::Eyapp](http://search.cpan.org/~casiano/Parse-Eyapp/) module, which is very similar to standard yacc.

When I added support for single-operand operators (not sure what is the correct name - operators like 12!, or @@ 'value'), when compiling the grammar to perl, I got:

```
14 shift/reduce conflicts
```

I had it also earlier, but I solved it by adding appropriate %left and %right, but this time I'm at loss, since the problem seems to be from conflict between 1-operand operators, and more traditional two-operand ones.

Full grammar is too long to put in here, so I'll just [link to it](https://raw.github.com/depesz/Pg-SQL-Parser/master/helper/SQL.eyp).

To compile it, I use command:

```
eyapp -m Pg::SQL::Parser::SQL -o SQL.pm SQL.eyp
```

When running `eyapp ...` with verbose enabled, I get [this output](https://gist.github.com/3620078).

So, the question is: how to solve the problem in here?

Comment: Unary operators is the term you're looking for

Comment: These two rules looks very suspicious to me `expr OPERATOR` and `OPERATOR expr`. Are you sure this is what you mean? That the same operator can be on both sides of the expression or am I looking at the wrong rule here.

Comment: @Dervall: thanks for "unary" - somehow forgot about it.

Comment: @Dervall - yes. OPERATOR is a class that can have many forms. For example: @@, or ##, or @>@ or any other legal PostgreSQL operator. Some of these can be before expression, some after, and most - between.

Comment: Consider this, given the expression `A @@ A`, in your grammar there is no real possibility for it to know which of the reductions is going to apply `A (@@A)` / `(A @@) A` or `(A @@ A)`. I'd try to separate the operators in classes so that you know *which* of the operators are going on the left, which is going on the right and which of them goes in between. Does the problem go away if you remove those two rules?

Comment: @Dervall: I can make some tests, but there is no way to know which oeprators can be before, which after, and which between. PostgreSQL supports user-definable operators, so the fact that base installation of Pg doesn't have specific operator, doesn't mean anything when it comes to parsing queries.

Comment: (hate the fact that you can't have enter character in comment, sorry for multiple comments) - as for your reductions - sure, but syntax: a (@@a) would work only if there was a function a, and functions support is not yet in the parser. Anyway - I know that given string can be parsed into multiple trees, I just don't know how to specify priorities when it comes to unary vs. binary.

Comment: pretty soon SO will start suggesting taking this into chat.  I'm not sure why Dervall didn't write his "Consider this..." comment as an answer, since it's an explanation of the problems one encounters when parsing somewhat non-deterministic grammars.

Comment: Just to cut this for future comments - I know that grammar can be non-deterministic. I know about %left and %right. I just don't see how it can be applied (or something else, more likely) to solve this particular case I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aargh. Looks like I misdiagnosed the problem. The real cause of the problem were not unary operators, but cast (expr '::' normal_type).

Adding %left '::' at the end of priority configs solved the problem.

In case you're curious - [commit link](https://github.com/depesz/Pg-SQL-Parser/commit/49105093587a91285ca799b4246eebc96a2fb406#diff-1).